# Load video in share extension with Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, movie, share-extension

I'm working on an iOS app that provides a share extension supposed to upload a video from Photo Library to a server. 
I cannot find any example on how to handle the video.

Here is my code:

```
if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.movie") {
    print ("A movie has been chosen")

    itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.movie", options: nil, completionHandler: { (data, error) in
        print ("Loaded the video")
        if let video = data as? Data {
            // Do stuff with the movie now.
            print ("The movie should be loaded now")
        }
    self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler:nil)
    })  
}
```

The first `print` is printed, so I'm actually in the case of a `public.movie` item. But not the second and third `print`.

Can someone, please, tell me how the movie is passed and how I can handle it?

Thanks

Comment: Check if this example helps you http://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/share-extension-in-ios-application-overview-with-example/

Comment: Thanks but the example you mention is about an image which I already handle. I can't figure out how a video is passed.

Comment: share extension give you location(file url) of picked video item not video data

Answer (score 0):

loadItem runs asynchronously, and when you're working with a video file, the file size is much larger than images, so loadItem does not have time to complete itself before self.extensionContext?.completeRequest runs and closes the share extension.

The solution I found involved the following:

(1) Create a boolean variable that measures whether the loadItem function is complete, or not.

```
var loadItemDone: Bool = false
```

(2) Write a recursive function that periodically checks to see whether the loadItem function has completed.  If so, then run the completeRequest call.  If not, continue recursion. In my case, I check for completion once per second, which is why it says "after: 1".

```
func waitForLoadItemToComplete(after seconds: Int) {
        let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(seconds)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
            if self.loadItemDone == false{
                self.waitForLoadItemToComplete(after: 1)
            }else{
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success!", message: "Your file is uploaded!", preferredStyle: .alert)

                let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Yeah!", style: .cancel) { (action) in
                    print("User acknowledged file uploaded.")
                    self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
                }

                alert.addAction(action1)

                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }
    }
```

(3) Set the loadItemDone variable to true, when loadItem completes:

```
if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("com.apple.quicktime-movie") {

    // Do stuff with the movie now.

    self.loadItemDone = true
}
```

'public.movie' didn't work for me.  I had to use 'com.apple.quicktime-movie'

Also, DispatchQueue did not work for me, which is why I had to hack a bit...  I would love to hear a better solution from anyone more familiar with threads in share extensions...

Answer (score 0):

With the help of app groups you can do work around : http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions

1. Get video from library and save in Data in userdefaults.
2. Transfer the USerDefault key to via appschems and intercept it open URL method in app delgate of app.
3. With the same key load that video and forward it to server.

For references of app groups and Share extension : https://medium.com/@abhishekthaplithapliyal/ios-share-extension-930ba1ad3c3d